# Is there any way to add hover effects to svg files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Situation: Project with full png image, with layered png transparencies saved as SVG.

```
<html>
   <head><title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id="templatemo_header">
        <div id="site_title">
            <p></p>
            <p>
                <a href="#">
                <b>SUPPLY CHAIN STRATEGIC SOURCING</b>
            </a>
            </p>
            <!-- <img src="gifs/hidden_logo.png" alt="hidden logo" width="256" height="116"></img> -->

        </div>
        <p id="intro-text">#WEGSD (We Get Stuff Done) - Supply Chain Team
        </p>
    </div>
<div class="svg">
<svg xmlns:***lots of data
<image
     width="721"
     height="726"
     preserveAspectRatio="none"
     style="image-rendering:optimizeQuality"
     xlink:href="data:image/png;base64****lots of data > </image>

    <a class="fancybox letter-box" title="Invoice Processing" href="invoice_processing.html" data-fancybox-type="iframe" id="invoice-processing"  >

        <image
     y="37.4552"
     x="126.97877"
     id="image55"
     xlink:href="data:image/png;base64******lots of data> </image> </a>
    <a class="fancybox letter-box" title="Payment Release" href="payment_release.html" data-fancybox-type="iframe" id="payment-release"  ><image
     y="18.073133"
     x="367.49765"
     id="image66"
     xlink:href="data:image/png;base64*****lots of data> </image></a>
```

Link to live code: [Removed]
The layered images are supposed to slightly lift up on hover. This works in all browsers except IE. I've tried putting everything in DIVS, of various nature, tried various tags, tried IE conditional statements, and I just can't make it work in IE. If I intentionally break it with conditional IE statements, it throws the layered images out of alignment and just shows them as blank outlined boxes; which in turn do lift on hover..... `<image>` goes on for 9 times. No one wants pseudo code, but this is as close as I can get. Since I can't properly do show anything without going over char limit.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] rather than just giving us some pseudo code.

Comment: added link of actual code in use.

Comment: An example that's hosted on this site is generally best, assuming it's all client side you should just be able to copy paste the relevant markup into a snippet. (People are more comfortable clicking it and it won't change/disappear whenever you remove it, making the question more helpful for future viewers)

Comment: I agree. But since a lot of is base64....that's a lot of scrolling....But I can throw the whole html into the little code box if needed.

Comment: You're not doing it right then, we want a Minimal example, that should not require much markup.

Comment: Base64 uses a lot of chars. using only the first few tags to get a decent example of how it's structured is too much for stackoverflow and goes over the char limit. If you have another idea, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, a simple one is adding a style using CSS, like:

`.someclass : hover {
 background-color: black;
}`

check it out:
https://plnkr.co/edit/uyngUBVCU7yLPGUCUX2l?p=preview

Comment: That's what I thought. But what I need does not work in IE. My class name is "letter-box"  `.letter-box {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.letter-box:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -10px);
    transform: translate(0px, -10px);
}`

Comment: I've updated the plunker to your class, and it worked easily.
Can u create a new plunkr using your whole problem ?
thanks
https://plnkr.co/edit/jedejH4sqjpj3V9kcGgj?p=preview